# MySQL WorkBench 6.3 CE Config File location on Windows 10

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I was running a script and it kept timing out.

I found an article explaining how to increase the timeout to 86400.

The sql was still timing out.

After a discussion with a techie in our team he instructed me to increase it to 1 million and restart Workbench.

Now Workbench fails to start. Grrr....

Does anyone know where i can find this setting in a config file on the hard disk so i can change it back to 86400?

Answer (score 1):

Config and user files for MySql Workbench are located under

```
%appdata%/MySQL/Workbench
```

%appdata% is a placeholder for

```
C:\Users\your_user\AppData\Roaming
```

The file you are looking for is **wb_options.xml** and the key value for the param is

```
DbSqlEditor:ReadTimeOut
```

Comment: Congratulations for your first answer :-) Please keep the Q&A style for SO in mind. No verbiage please. Greetings, "Hope this helps" and similar should not be used.

Comment: @MikeLischke Done ;)